# How to run a specific function from a .py file from command line?

Tags: python, shell, tkinter, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a tkinter GUI project. in this project I can load files and run tests on them. I would like to be able to write a script which does this from the command line. This means I need to run the main script, lets call it view.py and then run 2 callback functions from it, each one is a callback function for a button. Lets call this functions load(file), run(). These function are member functions of 2 different objects that are being created in the view.py script. Their names are load_button and run_button.
How can I do that?

I can run the mainloop script view.py but dont know how to run functions that are defined in the file.

Comment: How can you provide the `file` argument to `load(file)` when running in the command line?

Comment: In my project I call filedialog.askopenfile() to choose the file I wish to load. I thought that I might just read this file in case that I call it via the command line.

Comment: Since you just want to call the two functions, I think you don't want to call `askopenfile()` for your case.

Comment: Yes of course you are right, Im planning to use something else when I'll call the function via cmd.

Comment: Then try `python -c "import view; view.load('file'); view.run()"`. But you need to put the GUI stuff inside `if __name__ == "__main__"` block.

Answer (score 1):

In functionFile.py:

```
def sayHello():
    print("hello world")
```

CMD:

```
python -c "import functionFile; functionFile.sayHello()"
```

(you can also import every function or just specific ones: `from functionFile import *; sayHello()` or `from functionFile import sayHello(); sayHello()`)

Comment: I tried it and it does opens my GUI but nothing else seems to happen. Can it be that the problem is a member function of an object? I called it load_button.load_callback()
The more curious thing is that when I close the window, the askopenfile() function is called. it is supposed to be called during the load function.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run the two functions without the GUI stuff in the command line, you need to:

- provide the `file` argument of `load(file)` in the command line
- put GUI related stuff inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block

Below is a sample view.py:

```py
def load(file):
    print(f"loading {file} ...")

def run():
    print("running")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import tkinter as tk
    file = "Hello.txt"
    root = tk.Tk()
    tk.Button(root, text="Load file", command=lambda: load(file)).pack()
    tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=run).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Then when you want to run the two functions without GUI at the command line, execute:

```
python -c "import view; view.load('/path/to/file'); view.run()"
```

Comment: I tried that, the load function is a memeber function of an object called load_button so I did just as you said but wrote load_button.load_callback('/path/to/file') instead.
This object is being created in the view.py script. The problem now is that it says that load_button is not defined. and when i try view.load_button.load_callback() it says view has no attribute load_button.

Comment: You need to state such requirement in the question clearly.  BTW create the object first before calling the functions.

Comment: Yes you are right I am sorry, I forgot about it. The object is created within the view script, I think that we should call the main script and then call the callback functions.
I have edited the question now.

Comment: If the objects are tkinter buttons, then you cannot get rid of the GUI stuff. You need to redesign your application to make the two functions independent of GUI stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a different approach. I made my view script to act the way I wanted (call these 2 functions) if I got arguments in the command line and it solved my problem.